# SVG no se redimensiona en Firefox

Tags: reactjs, svg, firefox

Estoy desarrollando una web en react, en una parte tengo un Box con una imagen en formato svg con un width específico. En Chrome me funciona bien, la imagen se redimensiona al width asignado, pero en Firefox no se redimensiona al tamaño que le asigno.
Intenté estas formas:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import logoST from '../assets/images/LogoSTL.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../assets/images/LogoSTL.svg';


function LoginPage() {

return (
//de esta forma me funciona correctamente en chrome
<Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'center'} > 
  <img src={logoST} alt="logo"  width={'20%'}/>
</Box>

//Aquí solo me aparece el espacio en blanco en ambos navegadores, pero no se muestra la imagen
<Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'center'} > 
  <svg src={logoST} alt="logo" width={'200px'} height={'200px'} viewBox='0 0 200 200'/>
</Box>

//De las siguientes dos formas solo me funciona en chrome
<Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'center'} > 
  <img src={logoST} style={{ height: 200, width: 200}} />
</Box>

<Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'center'} > 
  <Logo width={200} height={200}/>
</Box>
);
}

export default LoginPage;
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué en Firefox no está funcionando?
Estoy usando la versión 111.0 de Firefox

Comment: Versión de FIrefox?

Comment: Es la versión 111.0